# Wordpress Admin Bar appears at bottom and without CSS

Tags: css, wordpress, admin, blogs

After I upgraded to Wordpress 3.9, I noticed that my ADMIN bar is appearing on the bottom and it looks like it is not loading the CSS for it.  I have changed the theme back to the twenty-fourteen and it still is at the bottom.  So I know it is not theme issue but I have no idea what the issue is or how to fix it or at least disable it.  Also, it works fine on any admin page.

[image: Screenshot of the website]

Comment: check if `admin-style.css` didn't load?

Comment: Did you try to reinstall 3.9 on the update screen? Some files may have been corrupted in transfer.

Comment: I will check that when I get home.  Here at work, I can't install something like Firebug to see if it loaded or not.  I did read that someone found they had "Combine CSS" checked somewhere and that was causing the issue.  I am trying to see if I have that setting somewhere.

Comment: @codescribblr, I have not tried that yet.  I felt like that was a last resort probably because I don't know if that will break anything or delete anything.

Comment: Found it.  WP_minify has a setting about condensing CSS and that was breaking it somehow.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Check if you have wp_deregister_style('open-sans'); in your theme it can be the couse!

Comment: Thanks! I had `wp_deregister_style( 'dashicons' )` and that was the culprit.